# Leaflet JS Map: Driving Route with Multiple WayPoints (10+)

Tags: maps, routes, leaflet

The thing I am stuck with is figuring out a way **how to draw a driving route with multiple markers (waypoints) with Leaflet JS Maps**.

I want to achieve visually something like this: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html **but with Leaflet JS Maps.**

Can somebody help me, is this even possible with Leaflet JS Maps?

Comment: Wgy dont you use L.Polyline?

Comment: Yes, I can try with L.Polyline... it will be the simplest solution, I was wondering how can I do this with waypoints... :) Thanks.